# How to add specific requirements while submitting iOS app to Apple Store?

Tags: ios, requirements, app-store

I am ready to submit my iOS application to Apple Store. But I want to add specific requirements such as "app requires iOS 4 or greater ,iphone 4 , ipod  touch 4g,ipad ,camera & multitasking support". I don't know where should I set these requirements.

I set the base sdk & deployement target to 4.0.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key to `info.plist` file and set `still-camera` value.
[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3) is a table of all possible iDevice requirements.

As for target iOS version and backgrounding it's right to set deployment target at least 4.0.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I list the device required i.e. iphone 4 & above, ipod touch 4g & above

Comment: As I know, you can't list concrete devices. But all devices that are older then iPhone 4 and iPod 4G don't have front camera - you can use this requirement.

Comment: My application require any camera (back or front). So adding camera is not an issue but the devices. Here is a link where concrete devices are listed & submitted on App Store  http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/videolicious/id400853498?mt=8 Let me know if you find the way to list device.

Comment: There was a great site somewhere which let you select the devices you wanted to support, and it would suggest what hardware requirements you needed to set in order to achieve that. I can't find it at the moment. Anyone? I will update this comment if I find it.

Answer (score 1):

If you require iOS 4, you already have multitasking support.  There's no way (that I know of) for any user to disable that.

Camera is trickier though.  Make it **very clear** in your app description that your app requires a camera.  And that caveat ("you must have a camera") *should* keep non-camera device using people from downloading.

Comment: Thanks Michael for quick replyYes, you are right. iOS 4 has mutitasking support. But I just want to know where these requirements are listed ? Actually my application support taking photo from camera , so I need camera.

Comment: Just make it clear in the first sentence of your app description.  For example, "My great app takes your camera's pictures and adds a fun house mirror effect".

Comment: Thanks. But you didn't answer my question regarding where are you listing these requirements?

Comment: I gave a +1 to @brigadir because his answer was better.  And I hope you are all set!

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Brigadir is right. When you setUIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key to info.plist file & set the required values then it will automatically list the devices required. See Appendix C: Device Compatibility Matrix in itunes_connect_developer_guide.pdf.

Comment: I find the matrix in Appendix B.