# iOS xCode how to exculde iPhone 3GS from the list of target devices for iPhone distribution?

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, iphone-4

**How can I specify that my app runs on iPhone4 and above using project settings in xCode?**

More specifically, I'm looking for devices with retina displays.
I'm using XCode 4.1

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPhone and iPod devices with retina display have front camera. You can use this requirement.

Check this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8789015/326017